# Add a object to a nested json array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am starting to use jquery and the wonderful json. Now I have a problem that is maybe quickly easy, but I am still in my firsts steps and I can not see a correct solution. 
I have the following Object Nestead Structure:

```
{"Zpa":{"1":{"ID":"1","Liste":[]},"2":{"ID":"2","Liste":[]}}}
```

My question is: How I can add items to the array called Liste in each object item of my ZPA array?
I have been trying this:

```
$.each(zpa_liste,function(k){
    var row_liste = {"Var1":"Value1",
                     "Var2":"Value2",
                     "Var3":"Value3"};
                zpa_liste.Zpa.Liste[k].push(row_liste); 

        });
        var DataJson = JSON.stringify(zpa_liste);
        console.log(DataJson);
```

Well I always receive the answer from the console zpa_liste.Zpa.Liste `undefined`

If somebody could help me I will be thankful!

Comment: You'd have to do something like `zpa_liste.Zpa["1"].Liste` to get the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing a level?

the k in that function would be 'Zpa'

if you did this instead, it'll work

```
$.each(zpa_liste.Zpa, function(k, v) {
  ..
  v.Liste.push(row_liste);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `zpa_liste.Zpa.1.Liste.push(row_liste)` and `zpa_liste.Zpa.2.Liste.push(row_liste)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`{"Zpa":{"1":{"ID":"1","Liste":[]},"2":{"ID":"2","Liste":[]}}}` cannot be looped as you think. Inorder to do that you have to make some simple modification in the object

try `{"Zpa":[{"ID":"1","Liste":[]},{"ID":"2","Liste":[]}]}`
This one can be looped to produce required result